# WPF Binding Error Datagrid Converter SelectedItems

Tags: wpf, list, datagrid, binding, converters

I seem to be getting a binding error with a binding of the SelectedItems collection on a datgrid to a generic list in my ViewModel.

```
<DataGrid  ItemsSource="{Binding Path=ListOfObjects}" SelectionMode="Extended" SelectionUnit="FullRow" SelectedItems="{Binding Path=ListOfSelectedObjects}" IsEnabled="{Binding Path=IsDoingNothing}">
```

That's the plumbing bit... the error I get is thrown at runtime when I try to select an item from the DataGrid. It appears something to do with the default value converter converting the 'SelectedItem' object to my defined type.

I have done a little reading and I think I need a value converter of some kind? But I am a bit of a newb to this and would love it if someone could ref some examples that could help me that are related to this problem/plumbing/application of the datagrid.

```
System.Windows.Data Error: 23 : Cannot convert 'Stored Data Backup' from type 'MyType' to type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[Entities.MyType]' for 'en-GB' culture with default conversions; consider using Converter property of Binding.     NotSupportedException:'System.NotSupportedException: CollectionConverter cannot convert from     Entities.MyType.
   at System.ComponentModel.TypeConverter.GetConvertFromException(Object value)
   at System.ComponentModel.TypeConverter.ConvertFrom(ITypeDescriptorContext context, CultureInfo culture, Object value)
   at MS.Internal.Data.DefaultValueConverter.ConvertHelper(Object o, Type destinationType, DependencyObject targetElement, CultureInfo culture, Boolean isForward)'
System.Windows.Data Error: 7 : ConvertBack cannot convert value 'Stored Data Backup' (type 'MyType'). BindingExpression:Path=SelectedExcludedMyType; DataItem='MyTypeManagerViewModel' (HashCode=20097682); target element is 'DataGrid' (Name=''); target property is 'SelectedItem' (type 'Object') NotSupportedException:'System.NotSupportedException: CollectionConverter cannot convert from Dytecna.V001.Entities.MyType.
   at MS.Internal.Data.DefaultValueConverter.ConvertHelper(Object o, Type destinationType, DependencyObject targetElement, CultureInfo culture, Boolean isForward)
   at MS.Internal.Data.ObjectTargetConverter.ConvertBack(Object o, Type type, Object parameter, CultureInfo culture) 
   at System.Windows.Data.BindingExpression.ConvertBackHelper(IValueConverter converter, Object value, Type sourceType, Object parameter, CultureInfo culture)'
```

EDIT: (edited the title to) I was binding to the wrong property of the datagrid for my desired function. I have edited the XAML above... I want to bind to the SelectedItems, that's plural, not SelectedItem, so I can selectr multiple rows and bind them to a list in my ViewModel...

I don't get the above binding error, I just get a:

```
    Error   1   'SelectedItems' property is read-only and cannot be set from markup.
```

So how do I bind to it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ItemsSource="{Binding Path=ListOfObjects}"

is of type Entities.MyType, so you have to bind to a property of this type in your vm.

btw you just can bind to SelectedItem and not SelectedItems!

What you can do is to pass the SelectedItems with CommandParameters.

```
<Button Command="{Binding DeleteCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=MyDataGrid, Path=SelectedItems}" />
```

SelectedItems is type of IList!

Comment: Thanks blindmeis... I just noticed this in my code in the question! I had it working with a binding to SelectedItem, I'm now expanding the function to SelectedItems... this is where my problem is now. I have edited the question and marked up your answer, because for all intensive purposes you're right and I was wrong!

Comment: if you dont wanna use the Command workaround, there are some AttachedPropeties around for SelectedItems and Datagrid. e.g: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/keithjones/archive/2009/10/02/multiple-selection-in-a-datagrid-should-be-bindable.aspx

Comment: Niffty code... no errors and it calls the gets... so I guess it's bound ok. Just need the setters to work now. Looks like some time will need to be spent getting some understanding of this class then. I suppose it's better than doing it by recipe. What is the command workaround you speak of? I am an eager learner!

Comment: i posted the xaml for a simple ICommand (RelayCommand or DelegateCommand). there the selecteditems are not bound to the vm, but are passed to it with the commandparameters. this just works oneway of course;) so i cant selected items in my VM.

Comment: I think I understand, if I wire the command of the selectionchanged event with my SelectedItems passed back to VM I can update it this way... I'll give it a go and then update my question with the result. I can't figure out how to get the setter for the AttachedProperties method going and I'm more familiar with Commands. Not that I won't be studying the other method in my down time!

Answer (score 0):

Objects in ListOfObjects should instead have some IsSelected property; AFAIK you can't bind to SelectedItems.

You can then bind the IsSelected property to the IsSelected property of DataGridRow:

```
<DataGrid.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="DataGridRow">
        <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="{Binding IsSelected, Mode=TwoWay}" />
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip... I have noticed that I have made a slight error in my code from the desired functionality (writing the SO questioned was a good debugging exercise) and the change has thown up a new error! I've edited the above question in line with this.

Answer (score 0):

I just want to add piece of useful code to @blindmeis answer.

When you use binding from @blindmeis example you will get SelectedItems as object. It take me some time to find how cast it to IList. Here you are:

```
private void DeleteCommand(object param) {
System.Collections.IList itemsList = (System.Collections.IList)SelectedItems;
var collection = items.Cast<item>();
```

}